# Python code running on one computer, but not another

Tags: python, debugging, usb, libusb

I have created an application with the Python rfcat library. This application works with Python 2.7.8 on computer A, but not with Python 2.7.3 on computer B. Is this caused by the different versions of Python/[libusb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libusb) or is there another underlying issue that I fail to detect?

This is the error message I am getting on computer B:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
  File "/root/garageDoorOpener/rflib/cc1111client.py", line 654, in runEP5_recv
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'USBError'
```

- Verbous output from computer A: http://pastie.org/9823908
- Verbous output from computer B: http://pastie.org/9823907

Here are the versions of the software I am using:

*Computer A:*

- Python version:2.7.8
- libusb version:1.0.19
- pyusb version:1.0.0b2
- rflib version:305

*Computer B:*

- Python version:2.7.3
- libusb version:1.0.8
- pyusb version:1.0.0b2
- rflib version:305

What may be causing this?

- I upgraded from libusb 1.0.8 to libusb 1.0.19 on computer B and got the same error.

Comment: It looks like B might be a 64 bit machine? Where A is 32 bit?  What does 'uname -a' return on both?  And did you just copy over the whole directory?  Specifically the .pyc files?

Comment: @Isaac They're both 64-bit. I have compiled the pyc files on each separate machine. To verify this, I ran the following on both machines and then started the program: "find . -iname "*.pyc" | xargs rm". Still same error..

Computer B: Linux isengard 3.2.45 #1 SMP Fri May 31 20:05:26 CDT 2013 x86_64 AMD Athlon(tm) 64 Processor 3400+ AuthenticAMD GNU/Linux

Computer A: Linux edolin 3.17.2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Oct 30 20:49:39 CET 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux